# What exactly is a tangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm self learning differential geometry and got confused by the definition of tangent space. The note I'm using defines tangent space of a smooth manifold $X\subset R^N$ with parametrization $f:U\rightarrow X$ as follow:
$$T_xX=df_0(R^N) $$
where
$$df_x=lim\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}$$
and$f(0)=x$.

So I suppose that if $f:R^N\rightarrow R$, the tangent space would consist of real numbers. However, when I was reading the example on page 4 of this note (https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/TMA4190V2018/TMA4190_Lecture12.pdf), it states that the tangent space of a $f:R^3 \rightarrow R$ is $span\{(-z,0,x),(0,-z,y)\}$ which is not an output of the $df_x$ defined previously. Can someone please explain what exactly a tangent space is? Any help would be appreciated.

---

I realized that I mistook the direction of the map in the example mentioned above.

Comment: You should refrase the question, which is almost incomprehensible. Tangent space to a manifold? What has to do the function $f$? $df$ is the differential of the function, is something totally different (though related). Consult before "tangent space" on wiki.

Comment: Your question does not make sense in its present form. For example, $df_x$ is certainly not defined as in your question. I therefore voted to close your question because it needs clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tangent space should be thought of as a something straight (a Euclidean space) that is locally (near the point) looks like your space, therefore tangent spaces at a point $x$ of your manifold $X$ and its open subset containing $x$ should be the same (because a tangent space is a local object, i.e. it depends only on local data).

Then you can take a chart $U$ containing $x$. By definition of a chart, you have a diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U$ (which takes a point $y$ to $x$). Moreover, a tangent space should be something that is invariant under diffeomorphisms and it is functoral, namely if you have a tangent vector at $y$, then you should be able to push it and obtain a tangent vector at $x$. This procedure is called a differential, i.e. a differential is a map on tangent spaces. Then the authors say that to describe a tangent space at $x$ you should take a chart and apply the differential to your map and you obtain a desirable tangent space. Of course, a tangent space at $y$ can be canonically identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$, so all you need is to compute a differential.